# Why doesn't Disk Image Writer work?

Tags: debian, pcmanfm

I use the file manager PCManFM in Debian 8 (Stable). When I right-click on a disk image file and select *Disk Image Writer*, an error message is displayed on the standard error stream saying that the file "does not appear to be a regular file".

I know that the file is OK, since if I write the disk image with the `dd` command it works as expected. Any clues? Do I need to install any additional packages to make Disk Image Writer work?

Edit: The error message is

```
file:///home/august/Downloads/ignition.img does not appear to be a regular file
```

Comment: Can you replace the quoted error message with the actual text that was output to standard error.

Comment: @richard I have added the error message.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /home/august/Downloads/ignition.img`, and `file /home/august/Downloads/ignition.img` ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because `PCManFM` is converting the filename to a URL, and the `disk image writer`, does not understand URLs. I do not know `PCManFM`, but on similar tools you can configure how it passes parameters.

Comment: Do you happen to know which application Disk Image Writer refers to?

Comment: You will need to look at the configuration, to find out. Is the configuration UN-altered by you? If so you may have found a bug.